# What is the metal brace on the prisoners arm?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-homecoming

The Post credits scene of *Spider-Man: Homecoming* depicts Toomes being approached in prison by another prisoner, with a scorpion tattoo on his neck. Given the profile of the actor (Michael Mando) and the tattoo itself, this is  plausibly Mac Gargan (The Scorpion).

He appears to have a metallic structure over his prison jumpsuit, attached to his right arm that can be glimpsed briefly as he confronts Toomes.

There is little in universe to explain this yet, but is there anything in the wider Marvel canon that would indicate what this is. It appears to be a brace of some kind, and in order for it not to be confiscated would likely be fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There is little in universe to explain this yet

He's definitely Mac Gargan...he was **specifically** identified on the Staten Island Ferry.

[image]

He's injured during the fight on the ferry when he's hit by **a car**.

[image]

It seems likely that the brace is "fixing" the broken bones he sustained by that impact. **Note the bandages / cast on the arm**

Here's a better look at it.

[image]

Comment: ahhh! I see! so it's just a medical brace! I was thinking it was something to do with his Scorpion characterisation!

Comment: Not impossible but that would more likely be a something attached to his *back*...for the tail.